# Significance of trailing slashes in 301 RewritesRules

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've been given some rewrite rules to add to a server that differ from the standard format I use, I always include trailing slashes but I was wondering if they are necessary.

In the example below are the trailing slashes needed? What affect do they heave?

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/?$ http://destinationUrl/ [L,R=301]
```

Also, I understand the `?` makes it optional, but what effect would missing the `?` have on a long list of rewrites?

Comment: Whether you should be redirecting based on an _optional_ trailing slash is perhaps dependent on your particular project. From your example it perhaps looks like you are canonicalising the URL to one that _always_ has a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `/?`, `http://example.com/subfolder/` will not get redirected.
With `/`, `http://example.com/subfolder` won't get redirected.

It is just a way to capture the slashes if they are present in the incoming URL.

Comment: Please check the http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ site to test the values and see what I mean.